# Cypher: find node based on multiple relationship attributes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to make a query that find recipes containing all ingredients the user passed (an unknown amount).

I can find recipes based on one ingredient with this query:

```
MATCH (r:Recipe)-[:CONTAINS]->(i:Ingredient {name: 'carrot'})
RETURN r
```

For example, how would I find all recipes containing each of the following ingredients; carrot, pineapple, celery, tomato, ginger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Represent the required ingredients as a list, and use the [`ALL`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-all) predicate to check if a recipe has all ingredients in the list. The trick is that as long as you don't introduce new variables, you can use [patterns in conditions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#query-where-patterns):

> So, patterns are not only expressions, they are also predicates. The only limitation to your pattern is that you must be able to express it in a single path. You can not use commas between multiple paths like you do in MATCH. You can achieve the same effect by combining multiple patterns with AND.
>
> Note that you can not introduce new variables here. [...]

This query returns every recipe that has all the ingredients you listed:

```
MATCH (r:Recipe)
WHERE ALL(
  ingredient IN ['carrot', 'pineapple', 'celery', 'tomato', 'ginger']
  WHERE (r)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Ingredient {name: ingredient})
)
RETURN r
```

I guess you'll pass the user input as a parameter:

```
MATCH (r:Recipe)
WHERE ALL(
  ingredient IN { ingredients }
  WHERE (r)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Ingredient {name: ingredient})
)
RETURN r
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install a 3.1 version of the [APOC library](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), you can use the `apoc.coll.containsAll` *function*. For example:

```
MATCH (r:Recipe)-[:CONTAINS]->(ing:Ingredient)
WITH r, COLLECT(ing.name) AS names
WHERE apoc.coll.containsAll(names, {ingredients})
RETURN r;
```

(If you install a 3.0 version of the library, `apoc.coll.containsAll` would be a *procedure*, and the query above would have to be modified accordingly.)